# Remapp object with arrays from api with new keys and structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an output from my return object like this:

```
{
 data:
  [
   {
    ts: "20-10-26",
    events: 1500,
   }, 
   {
    ts: "20-10-27",
    events: 1280,
   },
   {
    ts: "20-10-28",
    events: 1111,
   }
  ]   
}
```

I need to have it look like this

```
[
  {
    id: "events",
    color: "hsl(331, 70%, 50%)",
    data: [
      {
        x: "20-10-26",
        y: 1500
      },
      {
        x: "20-10-27",
        y: 1280
      },
      {
        x: "20-10-28",
        y: 1111
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So what i need is to change the keys from ts and events to x and y. Also ad two fields with static data id and color. Im using graphs from https://nivo.rocks/line/ and they need the data formated as this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map the data array to a new array of objects with the specified keys.

```
data.map(({ ts: x, events: y }) => ({ x, y }))
```

```js
const responseData = {
 data:
  [
   {
    ts: "20-10-26",
    events: 1500,
   }, 
   {
    ts: "20-10-27",
    events: 1280,
   },
   {
    ts: "20-10-28",
    events: 1111,
   }
  ]   
};

const formattedData = {
  id: "events",
  color: "hsl(331, 70%, 50%)",
  data: responseData.data.map(({ ts: x, events: y }) => ({ x, y })),
};

console.log(formattedData);
```

Place the formatted data into an array if that is what your graph component needs.

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked great and a good clean solution. I was complicating it way to much. Again, thanks man!